# UITableViewCell Font size does not change

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview

I have a custom UITableViewCell that is being displayed in tableView. This UITableViewCell is generated from a nib file. The UITableViewCell has a UILabel in it.The code of this is given below.Apparently I have tried to decrease the font size to a fixed size and nothing seems to work.Here is what I am currently doing to set the font size.

In the UITableViewCell (this is the .m file attached to the nib) here is what I do

```
- (void)awakeFromNib
{
    UIFont *myFont = [ UIFont fontWithName: @"Arial" size: 4.0 ];
        self.LabelMyLabel.font  = myFont;
}
```

This is how the TableView is being created

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *TransferIdentifier = @"TransferTableItem";

    FileTransferTableCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:TransferIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil)
    {
        NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"FileCustomTableCell" owner:self options:nil];
        cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
    }

    //Set the text in the UITableViewCell here
    cell.textLabel.text = [self.MyArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    return cell;
}
```

I would appreciate it if anyone could help me figure out why my textsize is always constant (I have also decreased the font size of the label in UITableViewCell in interface builder) ?

Comment: Try moving your codes to `viewDidLoad` instead of  `awakeFromNib`.

Comment: @Wongzigii There is no `viewDidLoad` in a table cell.

Comment: Have you double checked your nib connections? is the label called textLabel?

Comment: Yes I have - I also redid them but its the same thing

Comment: You have a serious mismatch here. You are setting the text by saying `cell.textLabel.text` but you are setting the font by saying `self.LabelMyLabel.font`. Those cannot both be right. Is the label called `textLabel` or `LabelMyLabel`?

Comment: Oh sorry, I mean you can move the code to `init` method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The setting of the label's font is working. The problem is that you are setting the *text* of the wrong label. You are saying:

```
cell.textLabel.text = [self.MyArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

That's the wrong label. You want to set the text of `LabelMyLabel`, not `textLabel`. They are two different labels.

Answer (score 0):

Change `cell.textLabel.text` to `cell.LabelMyLabel` as it is setup in your nib.